# Use Tampermonkey/Userscript to organise UL List

Tags: html, html-lists, tampermonkey, userscripts

I am trying to order my search results using TamperMonkey/Userscript. The results start with Customer:, Case:, Inventory:, PNG:, etc. Below is HTML from the search results however I cannot find anyway to customise the order on these??

```
<div class="uir-tooltip-content"><ul id="uir-global-search-container" role="listbox" style="min-width: 550px; display: block;"><li class="uir-global-search-item"><a role="option" class="uir-item-view" href="/app/common/media/mediaitem.nl?id=3904965" id="/app/common/media/mediaitem.nl?id=3904965">PNG Image: <span>Bank Transfer Receipt Thermo Invoice 67578.PNG</span></a><a class="uir-item-edit" href="/app/common/media/mediaitem.nl?id=3904965&amp;e=T" id="edit_/app/common/media/mediaitem.nl?id=3904965" aria-label="Edit PNG Image:Bank Transfer Receipt Thermo Invoice 67578.PNG">Edit</a></li><li class="uir-global-search-item"><a role="option" class="uir-item-view" href="/app/common/media/mediaitem.nl?id=4380864" id="/app/common/media/mediaitem.nl?id=4380864">PNG Image: <span>Bank Transfer Receipt Thermo Invoice 71546.PNG</span></a><a class="uir-item-edit" href="/app/common/media/mediaitem.nl?id=4380864&amp;e=T" id="edit_/app/common/media/mediaitem.nl?id=4380864" aria-label="Edit PNG Image:Bank Transfer Receipt Thermo Invoice 71546.PNG">Edit</a></li><li class="uir-global-search-item"><a role="option" class="uir-item-view" href="/app/common/media/mediaitem.nl?id=4230494" id="/app/common/media/mediaitem.nl?id=4230494">PNG Image: <span>Bank Transfer Receipt Thermo January Invoices.PNG</span></a><a class="uir-item-edit" href="/app/common/media/mediaitem.nl?id=4230494&amp;e=T" id="edit_/app/common/media/mediaitem.nl?id=4230494" aria-label="Edit PNG Image:Bank Transfer Receipt Thermo January Invoices.PNG">Edit</a></li><li class="uir-global-search-item"><a role="option" class="uir-item-view" href="/app/common/media/mediaitem.nl?id=5049467" id="/app/common/media/mediaitem.nl?id=5049467">PDF File: <span>BOQ IB - Transfers &amp; BPAY - Thermogroup.pdf</span></a><a class="uir-item-edit" href="/app/common/media/mediaitem.nl?id=5049467&amp;e=T" id="edit_/app/common/media/mediaitem.nl?id=5049467" aria-label="Edit PDF File:BOQ IB - Transfers &amp; BPAY - Thermogroup.pdf">Edit</a></li><li class="uir-global-search-item"><a role="option" class="uir-item-view" href="/app/common/media/mediaitem.nl?id=5168179" id="/app/common/media/mediaitem.nl?id=5168179">PDF File: <span>BOQ IB - Transfers &amp; BPAY THERMO.pdf</span></a><a class="uir-item-edit" href="/app/common/media/mediaitem.nl?id=5168179&amp;e=T" id="edit_/app/common/media/mediaitem.nl?id=5168179" aria-label="Edit PDF File:BOQ IB - Transfers &amp; BPAY THERMO.pdf">Edit</a></li><li class="uir-global-search-item"><a role="option" class="uir-item-view" href="/app/common/media/mediaitem.nl?id=5661633" id="/app/common/media/mediaitem.nl?id=5661633">PDF File: <span>BOQ IB - Transfers &amp; BPAY.pdf</span></a><a class="uir-item-edit" href="/app/common/media/mediaitem.nl?id=5661633&amp;e=T" id="edit_/app/common/media/mediaitem.nl?id=5661633" aria-label="Edit PDF File:BOQ IB - Transfers &amp; BPAY.pdf">Edit</a></li><li class="uir-global-search-item"><a role="option" class="uir-item-view" href="/app/crm/common/crm.nl?id=1056272" id="/app/crm/common/crm.nl?id=1056272">Case: <span>C10118 You've been sent the details of a NetBank tra... (3077 Ascot Bathroomware)</span></a><a class="uir-item-edit" href="/app/crm/common/crm.nl?id=1056272&amp;e=T" id="edit_/app/crm/common/crm.nl?id=1056272" aria-label="Edit Case:C10118 You've been sent the details of a NetBank tra... (3077 Ascot Bathroomware)">Edit</a></li><li class="uir-global-search-item"><a role="option" class="uir-item-view" href="/app/crm/common/crm.nl?id=1262175" id="/app/crm/common/crm.nl?id=1262175">Case: <span>C12226 You've been sent the details of a NetBank tra... (2268 Tile Power Penrith)</span></a><a class="uir-item-edit" href="/app/crm/common/crm.nl?id=1262175&amp;e=T" id="edit_/app/crm/common/crm.nl?id=1262175" aria-label="Edit Case:C12226 You've been sent the details of a NetBank tra... (2268 Tile Power Penrith)">Edit</a></li><li class="uir-global-search-item"><a role="option" class="uir-item-view" href="/app/crm/common/crm.nl?id=1395573" id="/app/crm/common/crm.nl?id=1395573">Case: <span>C13603 You've been sent the details of a NetBank tra... (0378 Solartex Insulation)</span></a><a class="uir-item-edit" href="/app/crm/common/crm.nl?id=1395573&amp;e=T" id="edit_/app/crm/common/crm.nl?id=1395573" aria-label="Edit Case:C13603 You've been sent the details of a NetBank tra... (0378 Solartex Insulation)">Edit</a></li><li class="uir-global-search-item"><a role="option" class="uir-item-view" href="/app/crm/common/crm.nl?id=1624647" id="/app/crm/common/crm.nl?id=1624647">Case: <span>C15969 You've been sent the details of a NetBank tra... (0378 Solartex Insulation)</span></a><a class="uir-item-edit" href="/app/crm/common/crm.nl?id=1624647&amp;e=T" id="edit_/app/crm/common/crm.nl?id=1624647" aria-label="Edit Case:C15969 You've been sent the details of a NetBank tra... (0378 Solartex Insulation)">Edit</a></li><li><a id="showMoreItems" class="uir-item-view uir-global-search-more" href="/app/common/search/ubersearchresults.nl?Uber_NAME=transfer&amp;quicksearch=T&amp;searchtype=Uber&amp;frame=be&amp;Uber_NAMEtype=KEYWORDSTARTSWITH">Show more results</a></li></ul></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not the best way to do it, but you could try something like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=w3schools.com
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    // Your code here...

    var UL = document.getElementById("uir-global-search-container");
    
    if (UL.hasChildNodes()) {
        var LIs = Array.from(UL.getElementsByClassName("uir-global-search-item"));
        
        var newLIs;
        LIs.forEach(li => {
                UL.removeChild(li);
        });
            var moreLink = UL.lastChild;
        UL.removeChild(moreLink);

                LIs.forEach(li => {
                if(li.innerHTML.includes("Customer:")) {UL.appendChild(li); }
        });
        LIs.forEach(li => {
                if(li.innerHTML.includes("Case:")) UL.appendChild(li);
        });
        LIs.forEach(li => {
                if(li.innerHTML.includes("Inventory:")) UL.appendChild(li);
        });
        LIs.forEach(li => {
                if(li.innerHTML.includes("PNG Image:")) UL.appendChild(li);
        });
        LIs.forEach(li => {
                if(li.innerHTML.includes("PDF File:")) UL.appendChild(li);
        });
                UL.appendChild(moreLink);
}


})();
```

Comment: Thanks @Frank N. Apologies for the delay. This doesn't seem to work. Wondering if maybe it is because the search results come up as searched in the box not on page load?

Comment: Possibly. Sorry, my abilities are a bit limited. I guess, you need to hook into the function gathering the results to make the magic happen